# How media query max device height works

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm not an expert on CSS but based on what I've read, this is how min-width and min-height work in media queries.

Min width is the current width based on the current orientation of the device. Say, for instance, I had a device supporting 320x480 resolution, in portrait mode the width would be 320 and the height 480 - and in landscape mode the width would be 480 and the height 320.

I'm trying to find out if the same applies to device width and height - or whether is it fixed in relation to the device. In other words, if the device height in portait mode is 480, and I flip the phone the device height is still 480.

The reason, I'm considering using device parameters for some media queries instead of standard min/max is because the position can change if the keyboard is opened - so I'm looking for a permanent height as opposed to the fluctuating height of the viewport.

I'm struggling to find this answer and would appreciate any advice - also would like to know if there are any anomalies when using these queries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, max-width behaved the same as min-width.  When you rotate the device you will get a new max-width.

So your max-width will be larger in landscape than in portrate.

The same logic applies to max-height.